# Error al compilar el proyecto de android studio (BUTTON INVERSE)

Tags: java, android, app

[image: Error a querer compilar la aplicación de android, alguien sabe el por que sucede ? ya intente borrarlo pero vuelve a aparecer cuando lo compilo]

Necesito ayuda para resolver un problema del tema 23, me marca del button inverse y ya intente borrarlo pero vuelve a aparecer cuando trato de hacer rebuild o compilarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia en tu `build.gradle` la referencia a compilar (`compileSdkVersion`) con la versión 23 (Recuerda que debes usar la versión mayor) :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
...
...
...

}
```

Esto es necesario porque estas usando la [librería de soporte](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)!